# SQL Query Must Declare the Scalar Variable

Tags: c#, sql, variables, scalar

I have a class file where I declare `readonly string` of my query to be used in a method. I met the error of

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DBID"

May I know if I declare my variables wrongly?

Below are the code snippets:

---

**Class file:**

```
private static readonly string QUERY_GETMATCHEDRECORD = "SELECT [Title], [ItemLink], [RecordDocID] FROM [ERMS].[dbo].[Records] WHERE [ID] = @DBID AND [V1RecordID] = @recID AND [V1RecordDocID] = @recDocID";
```

---

```
public DataTable GetMatchedRecord(string DBID, string recID, string recDocID)
{
    string Method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        using (DB db = new DB(_datasource, _initialCatalog))
        {
            db.OpenConnection();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                string commandText = QUERY_GETMATCHEDRECORD .FormatWith(DBID,recID,recDocID);
                _log.LogDebug(Method, "Command|{0}".FormatWith(commandText));
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                dt = db.ExecuteDataTable(command);
            }
            db.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError(Method, "Error while retrieving matching records |{0}".FormatWith(ex.Message));
        _log.LogError(ex);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

---

**Program .cs file:**

```
MatchedRecords = oDB.GetMatchedRecord(DBID, RecID, RecDocID);
```

Comment: What does the line in `_log.LogDebug` look like? Shouldn't your constant look more like `WHERE [ID] = {0} AND [V1RecordID] = {1} AND [V1RecordDocID] = {2}`?

Comment: It logged the error message and method encountered: `GetMatchedRecord | Error while retrieving matched record | Must declare the scalar variable "@DBID". .Net SqlClient Data Provider | Must declare the scalar variable "@DBID"`

Comment: Where are you setting your variables? `FormatWith` replaces `{0}, {1}` etc. (assuming you're using James Newton-Kings extension method).

Comment: By the way, you should really use [parameterization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Comment: @gymcode, I was talking about this line `_log.LogDebug(Method, "Command|{0}".FormatWith(commandText));`, not the one in the `catch` block

Comment: @gymcode the error complains that you tried to use a variable or parameter but never actually declared id. Whatever `FormatWith` does, it doesn't add parameters to the command. Most likely, it breaks the query by trying (and failing) to replace placeholders with strings. That's how SQL injection attacks happen. Imagine what would happen if `RecDocID` contained `1; drop table records;--`. Quoting doesn't help either, `1'; drop table records;--` would still work

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Also, what is the **exact** value of `commandText`?

Comment: @gymcode if you want to simplify your code, use a microORM like Dapper. Creating aliases like `FormatWith` for common functions like `String.Format` doesn't help. You save 4 characters and get code that nobody else can understand. You could use string interpolation instead of `FormatWith` to make creating strings easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using '@'-notated variables will only work if you add the parameters to the commands parameter-collection.

try the following:

```
    using (DB db = new DB(_datasource, _initialCatalog))
    {
        db.OpenConnection();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = QUERY_GETMATCHEDRECORD;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBID", DBID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recID", recID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recDocID",recDocID);
            dt = db.ExecuteDataTable(command);
        }
        db.CloseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: Except you shouldn't be using [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: :D I really dont think that is of any concern to OP at this stage of his code. Nevertheless a valid point! Since the actual types cannot be inferred given OPs code-snippet I will not edit my answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger any "don't use X" drive-by comment is irresponsible if it doesn't also take the time to explain why X shouldn't be used. In this case, `.AddWithValue()` infers database types and sometimes gets it wrong, which can have bad implications for your database. If you're just dealing with small datasets and known datatypes, e.g. strings, there's no issue with using .AddWithValue()`. By the way, here's an archive link for the now-dead page you linked to: https://web.archive.org/web/20230206195816/https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/